# PayPal new mobile SDK app_id

Tags: paypal

Is the app_id returned from the proof of payment static? if so, is it available somewhere on the developer console and can it be stored on the database permenantly, and will it ever be changed?

I'm aware that the app_id is static on the Classic SDK console, but my question is about the NEW SDK.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2788518, Dave from PayPal here.

The app_id for the new mobile SDK is the same app_id as for the classic SDKs. It is static and can be stored.

Comment: Thanks Dave.
1. Can we use the new mobile SDK app_id for an app that runs MPL?
2. If we get a transaction through the new mobile SDK, can we refund it using the MPL app_id?

Comment: In other words, can we use the new mobile SDK credentials with the old MPL? We have to do this because we still have lots of customers using the old MPL.

Comment: @user2788518 I'll have to check on that and get back to you.

Comment: @user2788518 As you know, your MPL app needs an app_id to identify your account, while the mobile SDK (MSDK) uses client_id for that purpose. Both can be obtained from the developer console, and both are associated specifically with your account. Transactions made using the current version of the MSDK should be refundable using the MPL app_id. Future versions of the MSDK will work a bit differently behind the scenes; while you should still be able to refund MSDK payments using the MPL app_id, that combination has not yet been tested.

Comment: Just to be clear: An app_id obtained from the current developer portal should work fine with MPL. It is simply an "app_id", not a "new app_id". (But let us know if you run into any difficulties!)

Comment: Thanks @dave-goldman. I’m now confused about the client_id.
I have created a new sandbox business account called business@myemail.com, and I upgraded it to Pro. I need to use MSDK, MPL, RestAPI and the old NVP API against this account. What I need are the following values:

Comment: 1. API username, password and signature (I can get these from the developer console after clicking “Profile” on the business@myemail.com account). I want to use these to do refund and DoDirectpayment operations using the old API. No problem here.
2. Receiver email. I can use the same email business@myemail.com. No problem here.
3. Client ID and Secret key. I can only get these from the developer console using the automatic sandbox app. These values are associated with payment-facilitator@myemail.com. How can get these values for business@myemail.com ?

Comment: In summary, I want to use the same paypal account and the same app_id for all our PayPal operations.

Comment: @user2788518 My expertise is really around the MSDK rather than general account issues. So at this point I'm going to turn you over to the standard PayPal developer support team. See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support for various ways to contact them.